# Getting Started With Twitter for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, mgtwitterengine

For quite a while now, I've been trying to find a good way to simply post updates/photos to a user's twitter account via my iOS app. I've looked at ShareKit, but I really need to be able to design my own UI. Also, I've taken a look at MGTwitterEngine, but am unsure as how to implement it. Is there a "right" way to go about posting updates to Twitter with a custom UI on iOS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Checkout Apple's WWDC 2011 video on Twitter integration.  It is neat.

Comment: I did take a look at that. Since I don't have iOS 5 though, I'm unsure as to whether it will work out or not. Can you design your own interface and just have Apple's twitter API process the text/images?

Comment: I have not used the new API myself.  But from the video, you can design your own interface and use Apple's new Twitter API as a delivery mechanism. (in iOS 5 that is)

Comment: Great. Thank you. Do you have any idea about Facebook integration? The articles on the Facebook dev site were rather confusing.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Facebook integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Apple's `TWTweetRequest` object, calls made to the Twitter service can now be orchestrated right through iOS without the need for an external framework or engine. Just look at the Twitter developer docs and make the calls you need, specifying the correct information in a dictionary for the process to complete successfully.